# How to test using mockk library kotlin for Handler class?

Tags: java, kotlin, mockk

Code:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private Handler handler;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

        handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper()) {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch (msg.what) {
                    case 1:
                    Handle message case 1
                    break;
                    case 2:
                    Handle message case 2
                    break;
                    Add more cases as needed
                    default:
                    Handle other cases or provide a default behavior
                    break;
                }
            }
        };

        Sending message with code 1 to the handler
        handler.obtainMessage(1).sendToTarget();

        Sending message with code 2 to the handler
        handler.obtainMessage(2).sendToTarget();
    }
}
```

Problem: handler object always gives null during executing the unit test.

Question: How to mock the Handler class to initialize the instance to handler object? Using the instance, I need to handle the message.

```
every { mockContext.mainLooper } returns mockLooper
mockkConstructor(Handler::class)
```

These lines do not work as intended.

Comment: What does it mean that the two lines do not work as intended? How do they work? And what is your expectation? Maybe add a bit more context of the test than just the two lines?

Comment: After mocking the constructor with mockkConstructor, are you mocking the methods on the handler with anyConstructed() or constructedWith() ?